# Exclude subdirectory from Expression Engine official .htaccess index redirect

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, expressionengine

I have found a great number of suggestions online, but none of them seem to work in my case. I have an Expression Engine install in the root of my site. In a subdirectory named "helpone", I have installed WordPress.

The Expression Engine .htaccess is redirecting domain.com/helpone so that I can not access my WP install.

In EE's root .htaccess, the following official rule is used to handle the EE file system:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

```
    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

</IfModule>

I need to add an exclusion, so that when users go to domain.com/helpone -- it functions like a normal WP site.

What exact rule or condition to I need to add and on what line do I need to place it?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**UPDATE** 5/23

The problem, in my case, was caused by a weird Hostgator issue. I had a password set on my WP directory because it was in development. When I added any exclusion that would let me pass through to the WP install, it would kill all the navigation on the root site. None of the links would work anymore. I ended up leaving both the EE .htaccess and the WP .htaccess alone (I didn't add an exception), but removing the password from the WP /helpone directory, and it worked fine.

Comment: If any of these answers work from you, please accept one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# ExpressionEngine
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^helpone
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# WP
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^helpone
RewriteRule .? /helpone/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like this to the top of the rewrite rule:

`RewriteRule ^(helpone) - [L]`

the [L] will say "last rule" for the regex that matches helpone. Nothing else will be applied... I think.

Answer (score 0):

I have an installation of ExpressionEngine, WordPress and PHPBB under the same domain and server folder. For WordPress you can add at the end of your current .htaccess file of your root directory the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?yourwebsite.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ helpone [L]
```